# Using geopandas to explore a geojson LineString

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas

I have the following python code:

```
import geopandas

data = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "GeometryCollection",
                "geometries": [
                    {
                        "type": "LineString",
                        "coordinates": [
                            [-118, 32], [-119, 33], [-120, 34], [-121, 35], [-122, 36], [-123, 37], [-124, 38]
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "provider": "MyProvider"
            }
        }
    ]
}

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_features(data)
gdf.explore()
```

when I run this, it generates the warning:

> UserWarning: GeoJsonTooltip is not configured to render for GeoJson
> GeometryCollection geometries. Please consider reworking these
> features: [{'provider': 'MyProvider'}] to MultiPolygon for full
> functionality.

And the tiles on the map do not load, although, the line, defined by the geojson data does show up.

[image: explore result]

If I use just gdf.plot(), I get the expected image:

[image: plot result]

But, I want the interactive map tiles that using .explore() provides.

What does the warning mean exactly? How does my data need to change so this will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background / base map problem should be solved by explicitly assigning a CRS to your Geodataframe (I assume it is EPSG:4326):

```
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_features(data)  
gdf = gdf.set_crs(4326)
gdf.explore()
```

Alternatively, as you have written in your comment, set the crs while creating the geodataframe.

```
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_features(data, crs=4326)
```

Regarding the warning, I looks like for the tooltip to function properly, a different geometry type is needed (see [here](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/929) for a discussion of the problem - seems to be a problem with "type": "GeometryCollection").

E.g. for the following geojson definition the labels works flawlessly:

```
data = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": 
                    {
                        "type": "LineString",
                        "coordinates": [
                            [-118, 32], [-119, 33], [-120, 34], [-121, 35], [-122, 36], [-123, 37], [-124, 38]
                        ]
                    },
            "properties": {
                "provider": "MyProvider"
            }
        }]
    }
```

Comment: The tooltip warning was resolved with your helpful suggestion. However, the map tiles are not loading after adding `gdf.set_crs(4326)`

Comment: What does work is doing `gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_features(data, crs=4326)`. Apparently, crs needs to be set when creating the dataframe.  If you wanted to update your answer to make this suggestion, I will mark it as the correct answer. If you can explain why it works where `.set_crs` does not, all the better.

Comment: Both ways work, there should be no difference. Do you get an error message?

Comment: The issue was that I did not include the `gdf = ` part of that line. Trivial error.